# Blazor Web Assembly - Lazy Loading .resources.dll

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM project 'Project A' that Lazy Loads a Razor Class Library project 'Project B'.

Project B contains some resources (.resx files) with the following folder structure

```
-Project B
    -Resources (directory)
        - MyResources.resx (Public)
        - MyResources.el-GR.resx (No Code generation)
```

When I build and run Project A, the .dll containing Project's B resources is loaded as shown in the following pictures:

The Dlls and resources that exist when the application is running:
[image: ranA.PNG]

[image: dlls]

My issue is that I can't figure out why when I publish Project A, the .dll containing Project's B resources is not loaded as a satellite assembly, therefore the resources cannot be accessed.
 
Published blazor.boot.json

[image]

Visual Studio 22

Dotnet version: 6.0.300

Comment: Why you think Project's B resources is loaded as a satellite assembly ? Read [Create satellite assemblies for .NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-satellite-assemblies) to know more.

Comment: @QingGuo Made an edit, added the correct photo. This was what I was expecting when publishing the project since satelite resources exist in the running version of blazor.boot.json